# Finding Integer part of a square root of long integer on python

Tags: python, integer

I want to find out an integer part of a square root of a number on python with pylab expansion
However, long(sqrt(n)) does not work on large integers.
Is there any way to find a integer part of square root of a very large number very quickly?
I'm new to python and programming. All I know is while loops and if statements.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: x=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

In [13]: int(x**0.5)
Out[13]: 3162277660168379365112938496L

In [14]: long(x**0.5)
Out[14]: 3162277660168379365112938496L
```

Did I understand your question correctly?